# How wallets/ miners differentiate bitcoin and bitcoin cash (forks of cryptos)? (technical IT question)

Tags: mining-theory, miner-configuration

I could not find the answer by web search. People usually interested in economic differences. I guess it is a question for those who know how mining algorithms works.

Internet is kind of decentralized. But there is single domain servers grid that tells where to find google.com. In a world of cryptos, how do wallets know where to send your BTC / BTC cash transaction? How to differentiate between forks? Is there some list of agreed gateways like for TOR? If so who administers it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol administers it.

Usually, one coin's blockchain will not be compatible with another's: for example, Bitcoin supports Segwit transactions, and Bitcoin Cash does not; whereas Bitcoin Cash has a high block size limit and Bitcoin does not. The point at which the two diverged is the point at which Bitcoin started mining Segwit blocks (which Bitcoin Cash clients will not accept as valid blocks, because they contain Segwit transactions), and where Bitcoin Cash started mining large blocks (which Bitcoin clients will not accept as valid). However, if there was a transaction that was valid on both blockchains (as may have been the case around the time of the fork), then that transaction can indeed be "replayed" on both blockchains, with both accepting the transaction.

Comment: I see. But how do wallets/etc find miners in general than? What internet address are transactions broadcast to?

Comment: @Martian2020 Your node will seek out other Bitcoin nodes, I believe first by querying a few DNS servers that will have known functioning Bitcoin nodes, then you'll be able to query those Bitcoin nodes for the nodes that they're connected to, so on and so forth, until you have sufficient nodes you're connected to. Then, you only stay connected to each node if the information they send you validates against the rules of the blockchain you're expecting (for example, if you're connected to Bitcoin nodes, you only stay connected to them if the blocks they send you are valid Bitcoin blocks).